# у меня ошибка в паскале вылезает

Tags: pascal

```
program tabulation;

const
  a = -3;   // начальное значение x
  b = 3;    // конечное значение x
  h = 0.3;  // шаг

var
  x, min_x, min_fi, fi: real;

begin
  fi := 0.0;
  min_fi := fi(a);  // инициализируем минимальное значение функции
  min_x := a;       // и соответствующий аргумент
  writeln('x':10, 'fi(x)':15);
  for x := a to b step h do
  begin
    fi := 3 * sqr(x) + 2 * cos(x);
    writeln(x:10:2, fi:15:4);
    if fi < min_fi then
    begin
      min_fi := fi;
      min_x := x;
    end;
  end;
  writeln('Минимальное значение функции равно ', min_fi:0:4,
          ' и достигается при x = ', min_x:0:2);
end.
```

main.pas(13,15) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "(" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
вот ошибка

Answer (score 2):

```
min_fi := fi(a);
```

Здесь написано, будто fi - функция, а у вас это просто переменная.

По смыслу вы должны объявить и реализовать функцию вроде

```
function fi(u:double):double;
  здесь тело функции
```

Но далее в цикле у вас просто значение выражения для fi вычисляется без функции

P.S.  `step h`  - это где такое, в АБЦ из бейсика взяли?

цикл переделайте:

```
x := a;
while x <= b do begin
  ...
  x := x + h;
end;
```

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за глупый вопрос(я просто сам не особо разбираюсь в паскале, нужна другу помощь, а все источники информации иссякли), но как выглядит исправленный код ну или куда вставить исправленный код и как?

Comment: Ох, понятно...  ограничимся  `min_fi := fi;`

Comment: эхх. не сработало. уже раньше пытался но оно еще больше ошибок выдает и это превращается в настоящий клубок из ошибок.
main.pas(16,7) Error: Ordinal expression expected
main.pas(16,19) Fatal: Syntax error, "DO" expected but "identifier STEP" found
сейчас это выдало. Простите что так криво пишется

Comment: Я уже отметил, что в нормальном паскале step нет. И цикл for только по целым (перечислимым) делается

Comment: Неа. тоже так делал и там еще больше ошибок появляется, но все равно спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете переменную fi, как функцию, отсюда и ошибка.